# MySQL LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN etc, complicated query, PHP + MySQL for a forum

Tags: php, mysql, forum

So I've got a little forum I'm trying to get data for, there are 4 tables, forum, forum_posts, forum_threads and users. What i'm trying to do is to get the latest post for each forum and giving the user a sneak peek of that post, i want to get the number of posts and number of threads in each forum aswell. Also, i want to do this in one query. So here's what i came up with:

```
SELECT lfx_forum_posts.*, lfx_forum.*, COUNT(lfx_forum_posts.pid) as posts_count,
    lfx_users.username,
    lfx_users.uid,
    lfx_forum_threads.tid, lfx_forum_threads.parent_forum as t_parent, 
    lfx_forum_threads.text as t_text, COUNT(lfx_forum_threads.tid) as thread_count
    FROM
    lfx_forum
    LEFT JOIN
    (lfx_forum_threads
        INNER JOIN
        (lfx_forum_posts
            INNER JOIN lfx_users
            ON lfx_users.uid = lfx_forum_posts.author)
        ON lfx_forum_threads.tid = lfx_forum_posts.parent_thread AND lfx_forum_posts.pid = 
                (SELECT MAX(lfx_forum_posts.pid)
                FROM lfx_forum_posts
                WHERE lfx_forum_posts.parent_forum = lfx_forum.fid
                GROUP BY lfx_forum_posts.parent_forum)
    )
    ON lfx_forum.fid = lfx_forum_posts.parent_forum
    GROUP BY lfx_forum.fid
    ORDER BY lfx_forum.fid ASC
```

This get the latest post in each forum and gives me a sneakpeek of it, the problem is that

```
lfx_forum_posts.pid = 
                    (SELECT MAX(lfx_forum_posts.pid)
                    FROM lfx_forum_posts
                    WHERE lfx_forum_posts.parent_forum = lfx_forum.fid
                    GROUP BY lfx_forum_posts.parent_forum)
```

Makes my COUNT(lfx_forum_posts.pid) go to one (aswell as the COUNT(lfx_forum_threads.tid) which isn't how i would like it to work. My question is: is there some somewhat easy way to make it show the correct number and at the same time fetch the correct post info (the latest one that is)?

If something is unclear please tell and i'll try to explain my issue further, it's my first time posting something here.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to get an overview of the structure of your tables with only one big query like that.
Have you considered making a view to make it easier and faster to run the query?
Why do you have to keep it in one query? Personally I find that you can often gain both performance and code-readability by splitting overly complicated queries into more parts.

But hard to get an overview so can't really give a good answer to your question:)

Comment: What is a view and can i create it in phpmyadmin or how would i go for that with a mysql-prompt? What i'm thinking is that i will have to do lots of foreach loops over all the data if i can't do it in one or two queries which is what i resigned to earlier. My hope was that one big query was going to go faster since mysql can do some optimising and such? Would i notice a big difference in speed if i used two queries and a foreach loop instead? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Views are virtual tables based on the data of one or more tables. That way if you got several tables with different data, you can create a view that holds the data you need from each row. You can then query against the view instead of the original tables. Found a tutorial on it here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to look into that! Right now i got it sorted by partly using this query and adding num_posts as oyatek said.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `num_posts` column to your table. Don't count posts with COUNT().

Comment: Should i add it to my forum table and just select it from there and then update it everytime i add a post? And why isn't count good?

Comment: 1) "select num_posts from forums where id=25" is faster than "select count(post_id) as num_posts from forum_posts where forum_id=25" 2) it's easier for reading - just select a column, no need to write excessive code... I always user columns num_... instead of count() when it's possible. Yes, just add this column to every table where you need counter. Also you can add triggers and your counters will increment automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Can we get some...

```
Show Tables;
Desc Table lfx_forum_posts;
Desc Table lfx_forum_threads;
Desc Table lfx_forum_users;
Desc Table lfx_forum;
```

Here's some pseudo code

```
select f.*, (select count(*) from forum_posts fp where fp.forum_id =  f.id) as num_posts,
(select count(*) from forum_threads ft where ft.forum_id =  f.id) as num_threads,
(select max(fp.id) from forum_posts fp  
where fp.id = f.id
) as latest_post_id,
from forums f;
```

Then go on to use latest_post_id in a seperate query to get it's information.

if it doesn't like using f before it's declared then make a temporary table for this then you update every time the query is ran.

Comment: Didn't really think of doing it like that, thanks! Just a thought though: when i'm in small scale, would it be faster to do as oyatek said and just go for a column called num_posts and num_threads? Or should i use count() from the beginning?